# Is this TypeError normal?

Tags: discord.js

I run my command and get this error:

```
(node:17432) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: (intermediate value).setColor(...).setDescription(...).then is not a function
    at Object.module.exports.run (C:\Users\eFhii\Desktop\Projects\Anastic\Bot\commands\warnc.js:19:63)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\eFhii\Desktop\Projects\Anastic\Bot\index.js:61:34)
    at Client.emit (events.js:215:7)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\eFhii\Desktop\Projects\Anastic\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\eFhii\Desktop\Projects\Anastic\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\eFhii\Desktop\Projects\Anastic\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\eFhii\Desktop\Projects\Anastic\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\eFhii\Desktop\Projects\Anastic\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\eFhii\Desktop\Projects\Anastic\Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:210:5)
```

And this is my code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const botconfig = require("../botconfig.json");
const colours = require("../colours.json");
const superagent = require("superagent")

module.exports.run = async(bot, message, args) => {
    if (!message.member.hasPermission(["VIEW_AUDIT_LOG"])) return message.channel.send(`**${message.author.username}**, ohne Berechtigung, wird dieser Befehl **nicht** ausgeführt!`)

    let warnMember = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0])
    if (!warnMember) return message.channel.send(`**${message.author.username}**, bitte tagge einen User um diesen zu warnen!`)

    let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");
    if (!reason) reason = "Kein Grund angegeben!"

    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(colours.maincolour)
        .setDescription(`✅ ${warnMember} erfolgreich gewarnt!`).then(m => m.delete(60000))
    message.channel.send(embed).then(m => m.delete(5000))

    let Sembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(colours.maincolour)
        .setAuthor(`Warnung!`, message.guild.iconURL)
        .setDescription(`Du wurdest aufgrund von **${reason}** gewarnt. Halte dich an die Richtlinien, andernfalls kann es zu einem CA (Community Ausschluss) führen!`)
    warnMember.send(Sembed)
}

module.exports.config = {
    name: "warn",
    description: "Warn a User",
    usage: "+warn",
    accessableby: "Administrators",
    aliases: ["w", "warning", "warnung"]
}
```

My discord.js version: 12.2

Comment: I fixed it <3 :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    const Discord = require("discord.js")
    const botconfig = require("../botconfig.json");
    const colours = require("../colours.json");
    const superagent = require("superagent")

    module.exports.run = async(bot, message, args) => {
        if (!message.member.hasPermission(["VIEW_AUDIT_LOG"])) return message.channel.send(`**${message.author.username}**, ohne Berechtigung, wird dieser Befehl **nicht** ausgeführt!`)

        let warnMember = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0])
        if (!warnMember) return message.channel.send(`**${message.author.username}**, bitte tagge einen User um diesen zu warnen!`)

        let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");
        if (!reason) reason = "Kein Grund angegeben!"

        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor(colours.maincolour)
            .setDescription(`✅ ${warnMember} erfolgreich gewarnt!`);
        message.channel.send(embed).then(m => m.delete(5000))

        let Sembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor(colours.maincolour)
            .setAuthor(`Warnung!`, message.guild.iconURL)
            .setDescription(`Du wurdest aufgrund von **${reason}** gewarnt. Halte dich an die Richtlinien, andernfalls kann es zu einem CA (Community Ausschluss) führen!`)
        warnMember.send(Sembed)
    }

    module.exports.config = {
        name: "warn",
        description: "Warn a User",
        usage: "+warn",
        accessableby: "Administrators",
        aliases: ["w", "warning", "warnung"]
    }
```

You aren't supposed to put a timer on the embed, leaving this here for anyone wondering how they fixed it :)